# Why don't people at least suspect that some supermarket products move on their own on Sausage party?

Tags: sausage-party

I know this is not a movie to be taken seriously, but I find this fact curious.

Although people cannot perceive every movement the food does, so for them it would be like the movement of an inanimate object, under several circumstances they should have at least suspected that some weird thing is happening.

For example the scene where the honey jar suicides itself should have the one that bought it wonder how something that was on the bottom of the shopping cart could fell outside of it, similarly how a sausage can go to the sill of the window even though it wasn't absolutely near it, or how a single sausage is suddenly on a table.

I think there's no explanation for this on the movie but maybe some reason was later given by the creators.

Which is that reason, if it exists?

Comment: Remember that Sausage Party is a comedy, not meant to be internally consistent, and even the characters acknowledge that it's an animated movie by the end.  Hope you find a satisfactory answer anyway!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple. Human-consumers don't give a damn. They are in a supermarket and they will not think more than 2 seconds about why the jar fell off the cart. They will simply think....'oops...broken...Let's get another one'. These stuff aren't theirs' yet and they won't think about it a lot.

Think about what you would do if something similar happened. Would you think about it more than 2 seconds? And if you wanted to do something about it what would you do? Tell the supermarket manager that their stuff is moving by themselves? Most probably you would think that your mind is playing tricks on you and you would go get another jar of honey.

Answer (score 0):

It is mentionned in the movie that you must be high (from drugs) to actually see them moving the way they're or speak with them. The whole moving and talking among the groceries seem to be happening in some other dimension (or whatever it's called), and once you are high enough, you can actually see that dimension (or whatever).

An example from the movie is *Druggie*, who got high enought on bath salts that the hidden dimension (or whatever) got reveald to him:

I think the concept of "being high to see them" is one of the many thought-provoking concepts in the movie, because no one can recall or have any memories from the high times, so no one can deny it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think you didn't understand my question. What I meant is that people doesn't seem to care to find supermarket products in totally out of place places. Imagine that the man from the video wasn't high on drugs, shouldn't  he be surprised of finding a lone sausage over his table anyway? Obviously not to the same point of hearing a sausage talking or seeing it has eyes and legs, but surprised anyway. I would surely be surprised.

Comment: @user2638180 Ah! I see.